How to find the index for a given list in a list in Python very fast?
I need a Python code that returns the indices from a list if all the numbers from another list are found on the same row.
What I tried, it moves very slowly on very large lists. Below, is an example of what I tried.
numbers = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 19, 21, 26, 31, 42, 44, 48, 53, 54, 58, 59, 61, 62, 78],
        [4, 6, 8, 11, 16, 19, 22, 27, 28, 33, 38, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 61, 70, 71, 77],
        [1, 4, 5, 7, 11, 16, 31, 33, 37, 44, 46, 49, 53, 59, 62, 64, 68, 70, 73, 78],
        [5, 7, 8, 15, 19, 20, 27, 35, 41, 42, 45, 51, 53, 55, 60, 66, 68, 72, 77, 80],
        [3, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 29, 36, 43, 44, 45, 53, 55, 56, 61, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72],
        [2, 7, 10, 12, 16, 24, 34, 40, 42, 43, 46, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 60, 65, 72, 79],
        [6, 7, 11, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 47, 52, 53, 57, 62, 65, 67, 68, 71, 72, 77, 78],
        [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 16, 20, 26, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 54, 63, 64, 65, 69, 72],
        [3, 8, 10, 15, 19, 20, 34, 40, 44, 48, 51, 52, 56, 58, 62, 66, 69, 70, 76, 77],
        [3, 7, 13, 17, 24, 28, 31, 36, 37, 39, 48, 50, 52, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 74, 79]]


find = [[7, 16, 20],
        [7, 16, 42],
        [7, 16, 52],
        [7, 50, 52]]



def searchForCombinations(combinations_list, results_list):
    
    for sublist_index, results_sublist in enumerate(results_list):
        for  combinations_index, combinations_sublist in enumerate(combinations_list):
            if not combinations_sublist in results_sublist:
                break
            else:
                if combinations_index == len(combinations_list) - 1:
                    return sublist_index
                    break
             
resultIndex = []
for i, combSublist in enumerate(find):
    resultIndex.append(searchForCombinations(combSublist, numbers))
    
resultIndex.sort(reverse=True)



print(resultIndex)


For a search like this, it may be more efficient to use a list of dicts rather than a list of lists, with each dict entry containing the index of the corresponding value.  But it really depends on how long the inner lists are, how long the top-level lists is, and how many sublist checks you're making.

Please properly specify the task. Currently it's unclear. And code can't be trusted as specification, too many people post code they say is correct but really isn't.

How large are your real lists? And are they always sorted? And what are the ranges of the numbers? And are the lists in numbers and the lists in find always equally long?

What do you consider "very fast"? Do you have a time limit or a complexity class in mind?

Is it guaranteed that every list in find is found in some row of numbers? (Your code makes that assumption, as otherwise it would crash.)

If you are working on big sorted lists concider using binary search algorithm.
See ([1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/)

I would probably convert the list of lists into a list of sets since we just want to know if the smaller list is a subset of one of the larger ones (and if so, what is its index).
Try:
numbers = [
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 19, 21, 26, 31, 42, 44, 48, 53, 54, 58, 59, 61, 62, 78],
    [4, 6, 8, 11, 16, 19, 22, 27, 28, 33, 38, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 61, 70, 71, 77],
    [1, 4, 5, 7, 11, 16, 31, 33, 37, 44, 46, 49, 53, 59, 62, 64, 68, 70, 73, 78],
    [5, 7, 8, 15, 19, 20, 27, 35, 41, 42, 45, 51, 53, 55, 60, 66, 68, 72, 77, 80],
    [3, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 29, 36, 43, 44, 45, 53, 55, 56, 61, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72],
    [2, 7, 10, 12, 16, 24, 34, 40, 42, 43, 46, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 60, 65, 72, 79],
    [6, 7, 11, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 47, 52, 53, 57, 62, 65, 67, 68, 71, 72, 77, 78],
    [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 16, 20, 26, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 54, 63, 64, 65, 69, 72],
    [3, 8, 10, 15, 19, 20, 34, 40, 44, 48, 51, 52, 56, 58, 62, 66, 69, 70, 76, 77],
    [3, 7, 13, 17, 24, 28, 31, 36, 37, 39, 48, 50, 52, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 74, 79]
]
numbers_lookup = [set(r) for r in numbers]

find = [
    [7, 16, 20],
    [7, 16, 42],
    [7, 16, 52],
    [7, 50, 52]
]

for test in find:
    print(f"Searching for match for {test}")
    for index, row in enumerate(numbers_lookup):
        if row.issuperset(test):
            print(f"\tmatch found at row {index}")

That gives me:
Searching for match for [7, 16, 20]
        match found at row 7
Searching for match for [7, 16, 42]
        match found at row 5
Searching for match for [7, 16, 52]
        match found at row 5
Searching for match for [7, 50, 52]
        match found at row 9


I have tested for now with your method and Anubhav Sharma's method on a list with 10000 rows. With your method I got the best times.

with my script: 289 sec.
with Anubhav's script (dict): 185 sec.
with your script (sets): 104 sec.

I will try other methods to see which is the best.

I renamed the variables as per my convenience
list_dump = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 19, 21, 26, 31, 42, 44, 48, 53, 54, 58, 59, 61, 62, 78],
        [4, 6, 8, 11, 16, 19, 22, 27, 28, 33, 38, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 61, 70, 71, 77],
        [1, 4, 5, 7, 11, 16, 31, 33, 37, 44, 46, 49, 53, 59, 62, 64, 68, 70, 73, 78],
        [5, 7, 8, 15, 19, 20, 27, 35, 41, 42, 45, 51, 53, 55, 60, 66, 68, 72, 77, 80],
        [3, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 29, 36, 43, 44, 45, 53, 55, 56, 61, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72],
        [2, 7, 10, 12, 16, 24, 34, 40, 42, 43, 46, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 60, 65, 72, 79],
        [6, 7, 11, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 47, 52, 53, 57, 62, 65, 67, 68, 71, 72, 77, 78],
        [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 16, 20, 26, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 54, 63, 64, 65, 69, 72],
        [3, 8, 10, 15, 19, 20, 34, 40, 44, 48, 51, 52, 56, 58, 62, 66, 69, 70, 76, 77],
        [3, 7, 13, 17, 24, 28, 31, 36, 37, 39, 48, 50, 52, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 74, 79]]


source_list_dump = [[7, 16, 20],
        [7, 16, 42],
        [7, 16, 52],
        [7, 50, 52]]

def count_dict(n_list):
    c_dict = {}
    for e in n_list:
        if e in c_dict.keys():
            c_dict[e] += 1
        else: c_dict[e] = 1
    return c_dict

def matches(dict_1, dict_2):
    dict_2_keys = dict_2.keys()
    for key in dict_1.keys():
        if key not in dict_2_keys or dict_1[key]>dict_2[key]:
            return False
    return True

def find_matching(n_list_count_dict, list_dump_count_dict):
    list_len = len(list_dump_count_dict)
    for i in range(list_len):
        if matches(n_list_count_dict, list_dump_count_dict[i]):
            return i
    return -1

list_dump_count_dict = [count_dict(n_list) for n_list in list_dump]
resultIndex = [find_matching(count_dict(n_list), list_dump_count_dict) for n_list in source_list_dump]

print(resultIndex)


Try making the combinations sublist and results sublists a set, and check if results sublist set is a subset of the other.

Assuming you want to know not only the row index but also the items indices in the row, you may use bisect.
from bisect import bisect

numbers = [
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 19, 21, 26, 31, 42, 44, 48, 53, 54, 58, 59, 61, 62, 78],
    [4, 6, 8, 11, 16, 19, 22, 27, 28, 33, 38, 45, 46, 52, 53, 54, 61, 70, 71, 77],
    [1, 4, 5, 7, 11, 16, 31, 33, 37, 44, 46, 49, 53, 59, 62, 64, 68, 70, 73, 78],
    [5, 7, 8, 15, 19, 20, 27, 35, 41, 42, 45, 51, 53, 55, 60, 66, 68, 72, 77, 80],
    [3, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 29, 36, 43, 44, 45, 53, 55, 56, 61, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72],
    [2, 7, 10, 12, 16, 24, 34, 40, 42, 43, 46, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 60, 65, 72, 79],
    [6, 7, 11, 14, 18, 25, 30, 34, 47, 52, 53, 57, 62, 65, 67, 68, 71, 72, 77, 78],
    [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 16, 20, 26, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 48, 54, 63, 64, 65, 69, 72],
    [3, 8, 10, 15, 19, 20, 34, 40, 44, 48, 51, 52, 56, 58, 62, 66, 69, 70, 76, 77],
    [3, 7, 13, 17, 24, 28, 31, 36, 37, 39, 48, 50, 52, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 74, 79]
]

find = [
    [7, 16, 20],
    [7, 16, 42],
    [7, 16, 52],
    [7, 50, 52]
]

for rowindex, row in enumerate(numbers):
    print(f"Searching for matches in row {rowindex}")
    seen = {}
    for testindex, test in enumerate(find):
        found = []
        lo = 0
        for itemindex, item in enumerate(test):
            if item in seen:
                found.append(seen[item])
                continue
            ip = bisect(row, item, lo)
            if ip > 0 and row[ip-1] == item:
                seen[item] = ip-1
                lo = ip
                found.append(seen[item])
            else:
                break
        if len(found) == len(test):
            print(f"\tmatch found for {test} at positions {found}")

The output is
Searching for matches in row 0
Searching for matches in row 1
Searching for matches in row 2
Searching for matches in row 3
Searching for matches in row 4
Searching for matches in row 5
    match found for [7, 16, 42] at positions [1, 4, 8]
    match found for [7, 16, 52] at positions [1, 4, 12]
Searching for matches in row 6
Searching for matches in row 7
    match found for [7, 16, 20] at positions [3, 5, 6]
Searching for matches in row 8
Searching for matches in row 9
    match found for [7, 50, 52] at positions [1, 11, 12]

This will be ~2x slower than JonSG's solution.
Note that I check each "find" sublist against all "numbers" sublist, not the opposite, in order to introduce a little optimization and avoid looking for the same item multiple times in the same list.

Is lo intended to be an optimization? It might make you slower, at least for large lists. See here.

It was intended as a, perhaps naive, optimization. But I'm not sure the case you linked applies here, because we have no duplicate values

It's not about duplicate values. It's just about running various binary searches on the same list, either always on the full list or with ever-increasing lo. When always searching the full list, the first "middle value" of the search, i.e., the first value to compare with, is always the same. And thus always in cache. Whereas when searching with ever-increasing lo, that first value is ever-changing and might not be in cache. Similar for the next few values to compare with in each search.

Interesting, thanks

Vanilla Python optimized sequence indexing

def find_exact_sequence(numbers, sequences):
    """
    Find indices of rows where the exact sequence appears in order.

    Args:
        numbers (List[List[int]]): 2D list of rows.
        sequences (List[List[int]]): List of sequences to find.

    Returns:
        List[int]: List of indices where sequences are found.
    """
    result_indices = []

    # For each sequence to find
    for sequence in sequences:
        # For each row in numbers
        for idx, row in enumerate(numbers):
            # Check if the sequence exists as a subsequence in the row
            if any(row[i:i+len(sequence)] == sequence for i in range(len(row) - len(sequence) + 1)):
                result_indices.append(idx)
                break  # Stop after the first match for this sequence

    return result_indices

Options

sets Try using sets, since sets have the set.issubset method, python will be using hashing to find subsets, this is perfect time complexity.

def set_based_find_rows(numbers, subsets):
    """
    Find indices of rows that contain all elements of subsets using sets.

    Args:
        numbers (List[List[int]]): 2D list of rows.
        subsets (List[List[int]]): List of subsets to find.

    Returns:
        List[int]: List of indices where subsets are found.
    """
    # Convert each row in numbers to a set for fast lookup
    numbers_sets = [set(row) for row in numbers]

    # Result list to store indices
    result_indices = []

    # For each subset
    for subset in subsets:
        subset_set = set(subset)  # Convert subset to a set
        for idx, row_set in enumerate(numbers_sets):
            if subset_set.issubset(row_set):  # Check if subset is in the row
                result_indices.append(idx)
                break  # Stop after finding the first matching row

    return result_indices



C Extensions. C extensions can speed up code, try using cython for ease of use.

arrays. since all rows are same size and datatype, use numpy array or some other library to create faster arrays.


import numpy as np

def numpy_find_rows(numbers, subsets):
    """
    Find indices of rows that contain all elements of subsets using NumPy.

    Args:
        numbers (List[List[int]]): 2D list of rows.
        subsets (List[List[int]]): List of subsets to find.

    Returns:
        List[int]: List of indices where subsets are found.
    """
    # Convert the 2D list to a NumPy array
    numbers_array = np.array(numbers, dtype=object)

    # Result list to store indices
    result_indices = []

    # For each subset
    for subset in subsets:
        subset = set(subset)  # Convert subset to a set for quick checks
        for idx, row in enumerate(numbers_array):
            if subset.issubset(row):  # Efficient subset check
                result_indices.append(idx)
                break  # Stop after finding the first matching row

    return result_indices



Choosing the Right Algorithm

Set-Based Membership Check: Best choice for large datasets due to O(1) set membership checks.

Brute Force: Simplest, but only practical for small datasets.

Binary Search: Useful if rows are already sorted or can be sorted once.


Advanced Large Dataset techniques

multiprocessing - for each row, have a process that searches that row for that subset.

import multiprocessing

def search_sequence_in_rows(args):
    """
    Search for sequences in a chunk of rows.

    Args:
        args (tuple): A tuple containing the subset of rows, sequences to find, and the starting index of the rows.

    Returns:
        List[tuple]: A list of tuples (row_index, sequence_index) for matches.
    """
    rows, sequences, start_index = args
    results = []

    for row_index, row in enumerate(rows):
        for sequence_index, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
            if any(row[i:i+len(sequence)] == sequence for i in range(len(row) - len(sequence) + 1)):
                results.append((start_index + row_index, sequence_index))
                break  # Stop after finding the sequence in this row

    return results

def find_exact_sequence_parallel(numbers, sequences):
    """
    Find the exact sequences in the list of rows using multiprocessing.

    Args:
        numbers (List[List[int]]): 2D list of rows.
        sequences (List[List[int]]): List of sequences to find.

    Returns:
        List[tuple]: A list of tuples (row_index, sequence_index) for matches.
    """
    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    chunk_size = len(numbers) // num_processes
    chunks = [
        (numbers[i:i + chunk_size], sequences, i)
        for i in range(0, len(numbers), chunk_size)
    ]

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
        results = pool.map(search_sequence_in_rows, chunks)

    # Flatten results
    flat_results = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
    return flat_results



SIMD - np.array_equal leverages NumPy's fast C-backed array comparisons.
Using a vectorized sliding window instead of manual loops, NumPy handles vectorized slicing internally. Numpy has a similiar implementation.

import numpy as np

def find_exact_sequence_simd(numbers, sequences):
    """
    Find the exact sequences in rows using SIMD-accelerated NumPy.

    Args:
        numbers (List[List[int]]): 2D list of numbers.
        sequences (List[List[int]]): List of sequences to find.

    Returns:
        List[tuple]: A list of tuples (row_index, sequence_index) for matches.
    """
    results = []
    numbers_array = np.array(numbers)  # Convert to NumPy array for SIMD operations

    for seq_idx, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        seq_len = len(sequence)
        sequence_array = np.array(sequence)

        for row_idx, row in enumerate(numbers_array):
            # Use a sliding window to find the sequence
            for start in range(len(row) - seq_len + 1):
                if np.array_equal(row[start:start + seq_len], sequence_array):
                    results.append((row_idx, seq_idx))
                    break  # Move to the next row after finding the sequence
    return results


Numba NJIT

from numba import njit

@njit
def find_exact_sequence_numba(numbers, sequences):
    results = []
    for seq_idx, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        seq_len = len(sequence)
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(numbers):
            for start in range(len(row) - seq_len + 1):
                if all(row[start + i] == sequence[i] for i in range(seq_len)):
                    results.append((row_idx, seq_idx))
                    break
    return results

